# is this function considered for inline?

Tags: c, gcc, inline, declaration

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void test()
{
    printf("is this function considered for inline?");
}

int main()
{
    test(); // definition does not have inline keyword. But declaration at the bottom (which is never used) has a inline keyword.
}

inline static void test(); // definition WITH inline keyword
```

Would compiler view `test()` as if `inline` keyword were attached to it?

EDIT: Sorry, I meant to have an inline keyword at the declaration at the end!

Comment: Did you compile with optimization on? And whats the last line about in your example code - that wont compile even

Comment: I don't think it's possible to know, save maybe for disassembling it. Is there a reason you need it to be, or is this just out of curiosity? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: I am sorry, but I had a HUGE error in my example code. I meant to have an inline keyword at the end of the declaration!

Comment: So, does it mean that using inline keyword is useless even for building a kernel?

Comment: @KerrekSB I was only talking about for optimisation purposes, not the other facilities of the word `inline` like templates and the ODR. I meant that the compiler probably has a very good idea what it wants to inline already, and doesn't give much consideration to `inline` declared functions for the purpose of inlining them. With that clarification, is what I said still incorrect?

Comment: @KerrekSB well if you can't then I can't, I'll delete my original comments to avoid confusion to future readers.

Answer (score 2):

Compile with gcc -S and see what the assembler looks like eg this is a -O2 - so we can see test() is gone and inlined. You should have a .s file generated by gcc

```
main:
.LFB12:
  .cfi_startproc
  movl  $.LC0, %edi
  xorl  %eax, %eax
  jmp   printf
  .cfi_endproc
.LFE12:
```

And without optimization we can see the call to test()

```
main:
.LFB1:
  .cfi_startproc
  pushq %rbp
  .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
  .cfi_offset 6, -16
  movq  %rsp, %rbp
  .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
  movl  $0, %eax
  call  test
  popq  %rbp
  .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
  ret
  .cfi_endproc
.LFE1:
```

Answer (score 1):

The best to find out is to just look at the assembly.

The compiler flag to make GCC consider every function for inlining is `-finline-functions`. This is enabled by default at `-O3`.

So at`-O3`, GCC will consider every function for inlining even if isn't declared with `inline`.

Comment: I am sorry, but I had a HUGE error in my example code. I meant to have an inline keyword at the end of the declaration! It changes the context of the question dramatically.

Comment: That's pretty ambiguous. The best way to is to just test it under `-O2` and see what happens. The documentation doesn't mention anything about this ordering. (http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html)

Comment: Yeah, even the standard doesn't mention anything about this ambiguity as well (it mentions functions with external linkage, but does not mention anything about static functions).

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to do like this. But the clearest way is just to declare the inline at the very first declaration, or the definition itself if there is no declaration.

Answer (score 0):

The `inline` keyword is much of a misnomer and doesn't indicate much of when a function is effectively inlined or not. If you add it to a *definition* it just ensures that when this definition is placed in a header file no problem with "multiple symbols" in different compilation units (.o files) occurs. Don't seek much more than that it.

If a function is effectively inlined or not is completely up to the compiler. This has even nothing to do if an external symbol is produced (your `static` definition). Most compilers have extensions to regulate that a bit (gcc's `__attribute__((always_inline))` e.g) and the only way to know is to inspect the assembler or object that is produced.